# agregar "!" a cada elemento de array usando map()

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo aplico el metodo map() para que a cada elemento de mi array le añada la exclamacion (!) tanto al inicio como al final de la frase? En Javascript

Esto es lo que tengo de momento

```
const frases = ['Labore sea dolor.', 'Justo rebum dolor.', 'Stet lorem amet.'];

const fraseExclamada = frases.map(x => )
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        const frases = [
            'Labore sea dolor.',
            'Justo rebum dolor.',
            'Stet lorem amet.'
        ];

        const fraseExclamada = frases.map(x => {
            return '!' + x + '!';
        });
        console.log(fraseExclamada);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Según la siguiente [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) con el método `map` se obtiene un ***nuevo array*** a partir de una función a la que se pasa como parámetro cada uno de los elementos del array sobre el que se ejecuta.

Comment: Muchas gracias genio de verdad

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacer tal que asi:

```
const frases = ['Labore sea dolor.', 'Justo rebum dolor.', 'Stet lorem amet.'];
const fraseExclamada = frases.map(elem => '!' + elem + '!')
console.log(fraseExclamada)
```

Siempre se puede consultar la documentación para saber cómo implementar las funcionalidades [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Con el método `map()` obtienes un nuevo array de lo que vas a retornar, en este caso, devolvemos a los elementos del array `frases` concatenados con los signos de exclamación `¡!`, ejemplo:

```js
const frases = ['Labore sea dolor.', 'Justo rebum dolor.', 'Stet lorem amet.'];

const fraseExclamada = frases.map(x => { return '¡' + x + '!'; });

console.log(fraseExclamada);
console.log(fraseExclamada.join(", ")); // para obtener todo en una cadena
```